# How to force a table's column's width to always be fixed

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table with 6 columns where one of the columns can become editable. I do this by hiding an *input* in the *td* cells of the editable column and display it when an *Edit* button is clicked. But when I display the *input* fields, the column increases in width. How do I force a column to stay fixed even if the content increases in width?

I'm using jQuery and Bootstrap. But any solution would help.

[Here is a jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/abwsbya7/1/)

html:

```
  <div class="container">
      <table class="table">
         <thead>
              <tr>
                 <th class="col-xs-2">A</th>
                 <th class="col-xs-2">B</th>
                 <th class="col-xs-2">C (edit)</th>
                 <th class="col-xs-2">D</th>
                 <th class="col-xs-2">E</th>
                 <th class="col-xs-2">F</th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
              <tr>
                 <td class="col-xs-2">(1,1)</td>
                 <td class="col-xs-2">(1,2)</td>
                 <td class="col-xs-2">
                    <div class="DIV_READ">(1,3)</div>
                    <div class="DIV_EDIT" style="display: none;">
                       <input value="(1,3)" />
                    </div>
                 </td>
                 <td class="col-xs-2">(1,4)</td>
                 <td class="col-xs-2">(1,5)</td>
                 <td class="col-xs-2">(1,6)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td class="col-xs-2">(2,1)</td>
                 <td class="col-xs-2">(2,2)</td>
                 <td class="col-xs-2">
                    <div class="DIV_READ">(2,3)</div>
                    <div class="DIV_EDIT" style="display: none;">
                       <input value="(2,3)" />
                    </div>
                 </td>
                 <td class="col-xs-2">(2,4)</td>
                 <td class="col-xs-2">(2,5)</td>
                 <td class="col-xs-2">(2,6)</td>
              </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
    </div> 

  <button id="EDIT_BTN" >edit</button>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#EDIT_BTN").click(function(){
    $(".DIV_READ").toggle();
    $(".DIV_EDIT").toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: You need to add fixed sixe to the input, not the cell where the input is.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set your inputs inside the table cells to be 100% width of the table cells themselves :)

```
td * {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can decrease width and height of your input elements.

```
input {
  max-width: 40px;
  max-height: 20px;
}
```

### [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/abwsbya7/2/)